# jQuery serialize in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, string

I'd want to know if there is something in javascript that can do the same job as .serialize() does. I'll need to use it `someform.onsubmit = funct...` or `<form onsubmit="...`. I need just to get all the data in that form (just as jQuery does) as a string.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you trying to avoid jQuery because of size?  because there are smaller libraries that have this functionality as well like [zepto.js](https://github.com/madrobby/zepto)

Comment: @castis it seems to be jQuery

Comment: @Jason Sperske It's not just about the jQuery size (in this work the size is not important), but jquery is not giving me what I expect

Comment: I tried with javascript and I am getting what I want... but I can't find any small code that will do as `.serialize()`

Comment: If you have a working js, why don't you just wrap it in a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the closest thing would be to use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/FormData).  Something like:

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open("POST", "/echo/json");
    xhr.send(new FormData(this));
});
```

This is arguably even simpler than calling `.serialize` on the form collection, but note that you can't inspect what is inside the `FormData` object apparently.  This is also relatively new, so not so cross-browser compatible.